# Why am I getting 'module' object is not callable in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, runtime-error

First, all relevant code

**main.py**

```
import string
import app
group1=[ "spc", "bspc",",","."]#letters, space, backspace(spans mult layers)
# add in letters one at a time
for s in string.ascii_lowercase:
    group1.append(s)
group2=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, "tab ","ent","lAR" ,"rAR" , "uAR", "dAR"]
group3= []
for s in string.punctuation:
    group3.append(s)#punc(spans mult layers)
group4=["copy","cut","paste","save","print","cmdW","quit","alf","sWDW"] #kb shortcut
masterGroup=[group1,group2,group3,group4]
myApp =app({"testFKey":[3,2,2]})
```

**app.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import static_keys
import dynamic_keys
import key_labels
class app(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(inputDict,self, master=None,):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.createWidgets(self, inputDict)
    def createWidgets(self,inDict):
        top=self.winfo_toplevel()
        top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        tempDict = {}
        for k,v in inDict.items():
                if 1<=v[0]<=3:
                    tempDict[k] = static_keys(*v[1:])
                elif v[0] ==4:
                    tempDict[k] = dynamic_keys(k,*v[1:])
                elif  v[0]==5:
                    tempDict[k] = key_labels(*v[1:])
        for o in tempDict:
            tempDict[o].grid()
        return tempDict
```

**static_keys.py**

```
import tkinter
class static_keys(tkinter.Label):
    """class for all keys that just are initiated then do nothing
    there are 3 options
    1= modifier (shift etc)
    2 = layer
    3 = fkey, eject/esc"""
    def __init__(t,selector,r,c,parent,self ):
        if selector == 1:
            tkinter.Label.__init__(master=parent, row=r, column=c, text= t, bg ='#676731')
        if selector == 2:
            tkinter.Label.__init__(master=parent, row=r, column=c, text= t, bg ='#1A6837')
        if selector == 3:
            tkinter.Label.__init__(master=parent, row=r, column=c, text= t, bg ='#6B6966')
```

Now for a description of the problem. When I run `main.py` in python3, I get the error

```
File "Desktop/kblMaker/main.py", line 13, in <module>
myApp =app({"testFKey":[3,2,2]})
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: As for your side question, use code formatting for errors/output as well.

Comment: The traceback you're showing us can't possibly be from the code you're showing us. And it also doesn't match the error you mention in the question title. So… please give us a code, traceback, and description that all match instead of making us guess.

Comment: @abarnert edited no idea while that happened

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have a module named `app` that contains a class named `app`.  If you just do `import app` in main.py then `app` will refer to the module, and `app.app` will refer to the class.  Here are a couple of options:

- Leave your import statement alone, and use `myApp = app.app({"testFKey":[3,2,2]})` inside of main.py
- Replace `import app` with `from app import app`, now `app` will refer to the class and `myApp = app({"testFKey":[3,2,2]})` will work fine

Comment: Or, better, name the class `App` instead of `app` to avoid this confusion entirely (and to be PEP8-compliant, for bonus points).

Comment: @abarnert: Upvote for the suggestion to follow PEP8 and rename it to avoid confusion. I assumed there is code using that module, so changing the naming would introduce issues. But this can be simply fixed by adding the following line at the end of `app.py` file: `app = App  # for backward compatibility`.

Comment: @fozbstuios: I think F.J's answer already says everything that needs to be said, and the comment was sufficient to cover the naming confusion… but since you asked for it, I added an answer as well.

Answer (score 10):

In `main.py` change second line to:

```
from app import app
```

The issue is you have `app` module and `app` class within it. But you are importing module, not the class from it:

```
myApp = app({"testFKey": [3, 2, 2]})
```

(you can also instead replace "`app`" inside line above into "`app.app`")

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as both F.J and Tadeck already explained, is that `app` is the module `app`, and `app.app` is the class `app` defined in that module.

You can get around that by using `from app import app` (or, if you must, even `from app import *`), as in Tadeck's answer, or by explicitly referring to `app.app` instead of just `app`, as in F.J's answer.

If you rename the class to `App`, that won't magically fix anything—you will still have to either `from app import App` or refer to `app.App`—but it will make the problem a whole lot more obvious. And make your code less confusing after you've fixed the problem, too.

This is part of the reason that [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends that:

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names.
>
> …
>
> Almost without exception, class names use the CapWords convention.

That way, there's no way to mix them up.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix this problem is: Go to Gradle, `build` (Madulus) and below the `buildTypes`, type the following code and sync the project.

```json
viewBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Now you can access to the binding. If the xml layout is `activity_main.xml`, it means the binding is `ActivityMainBinding`.