# Why my object is not callable when trying to send an OrderedDict to a vector?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This question is related to this other one: [How to convert this type of “Dictionary” into a Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60102667/how-to-convert-this-type-of-dictionary-into-a-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment106300965_60102667)

I am using Splunk's SDK to extract data.
The extracted data is presented as an OrderedDict.

Now I want to send it to a dataframe. But first I have to send it to a vector or list.
And I am getting the following error:

[image]

This is the code to extract the data:

[image]

And this is my attempt to send results to a vector:

```
for key, value in reader():
    temp=[key, value]
    dictlist.append(temp)
```

And I tried the thing in here:
[Why am I getting 'module' object is not callable in python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069716/why-am-i-getting-module-object-is-not-callable-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
items=[]
for item in reader:
    items.append(item)

import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(items)

df
```

[image]